# Is this right way to retrive data from context to solve full page caching issue in product detail page Magento2?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I have refer sign in functionality on header where use customer data from context to check that customet is logged in or not?

So Can we use similar concept for product detail page?

Is this right way or more reliable way than private content?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: We should not use directly code on phtml should work with blocks to handle the functionality on phtml file. Please tell me more what issue you are facing cache issue on product detail page only?

Comment: Do you know the concept of sign in and myaccount?
What i am talking about here

Comment: Yes, we can check the customer from Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH whether it is logged or not.

Comment: Yes , so my question is can we make same thing for product at product detail page for my custom page?
Is this reliable way in compare of private content in magento2?

Comment: If i am right you want to check customer logged on product detail page and product detail page is now your custom page you made?